# JPanel Design issue

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent

I have Form on which i am drawing oval on mouseClick Event. This works Fine for me. The Circles are painted. But When i Minimize the Form and Again Maximize it the Panel gets Refreshed and Circles are removed (i.e Panel is left Blank).

Code is :
I have a JFrame on which there is a Jpanel named jPanel1, on this panel circles are drawn.

```
private void jPanel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        count += 1;
        if (count <= clients) {
            drawCircle(evt.getX() - (radius / 2), evt.getY() - (radius / 2));
        }
    }

    public void drawCircle(int x, int y) {
        Graphics g = jPanel1.getGraphics();
        g.drawOval(x - radius, y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(x - radius, y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
    }
```

Comment: all boils down to _not_ use getGraphics() (as already mentioned in the answers, repeated just for emphasis :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, not only is it important to override your `paintComponent` method for the JPanel, but you also need to store the information about the circles you're going to draw.  You use that stored information to paint all the circles on the screen during the `paintComponent` call.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;



public class TempProject extends JPanel{
    /** Stores info about circles  */
    public ArrayList<CircleInfo> circles = new ArrayList<CircleInfo>();

    /** fields that were in example code */
    public int count = 0;
    public final int radius = 20;
    public final int clients = 20;

    public TempProject(){

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
                count += 1;
                if (count <= clients) {
                        // Store info about the circle to draw
                    circles.add(new CircleInfo(evt.getX() - (radius / 2), evt.getY() - (radius / 2), radius));
                        // Tell swing to repaint asap
                    repaint();
                }
            }});
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g ) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            //Iterates through saved circles and paints them
        for(CircleInfo circle : circles){
            g.drawOval(circle.x - circle.radius, circle.y - circle.radius, 2 * circle.radius, 2 * circle.radius);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillOval(circle.x - circle.radius, circle.y - circle.radius, 2 * circle.radius, 2 * circle.radius);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
                frame.setContentPane(new TempProject());  
                frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    /** Simple class for storing Circle info */
    public static class CircleInfo{
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int radius = 0;

        public CircleInfo(int x, int y, int radius){
            this.x = x; this.y = y; this.radius = radius;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson I forgot to add `super.paintComponent` until I saw your comment on the other answer :P Whoops!  Thanks for keeping me honest!

Comment: Glad I could help out, if only in that minor way.

Comment: @NickRippe Really a very gud Answer. Its really very helpfull

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to call explicitely draw functions outside the `paintComponent` method of your `JPanel`.

You should instead extends `JPanel` and put the `drawCircle` code inside `paintComponent` method:

```
public class DrawCircleClass extends JPanel
{
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawOval(x - radius, y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(x - radius, y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
    }

}
```

Swing will automatically calls `paintComponent` method when the Component should be redrawn (es. after maximize the minimized window).

Comment: When i Click to draw second Circle the First Circle is invisible. The jPanel is redesigned.

Comment: got the Solution.. I was Writing super.PaintComponent() method in paintComponent() method thats why it was getting redesigned.

Comment: It's important to note that if you don't save your circle info and repaint from that, you'll still have a problem with losing the circles on resize (see example in my answer).  You may have already addressed that though.

Comment: The code **should have** a call to `super.paintComponent(g)`.  If it only 'works' without it, it is broken.

Answer (score 2):

All the drawings must be done in paint method of panel. So you have to override this method in the panel and put the drawing code there

Comment: certainly you mean _paintComponent_ (not paint) :-)